# making dictionary from some logic

Tags: python

team 'A' , 'B' and 'C' did consecutive goals 12, 1, and 9 times respectively.

```
teams = ['A','B','C']

goals = [12,1,9]
```

Which team did 5th goal? Answer is team 'A'.
Which team did 13th goal? Answer is team 'B'.
Which team did 21th goal? Answer is team 'C'.

I want to make dictionary of team vs. goal number.
@Kevin answer is nice.

```
dict(enumerate([t for t,g in zip(teams, goals) for _ in range(g)], 1))
```

Then, given list is [5,13,21]. How to get list: ['A','B','C']??

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. The dict you want to make can't exist as you've shown it here.

Comment: It can't be a dictionary, at least not the way you've set it up, because dicts can only have one occurrence of a key.

Comment: As @Kevin said, dictionaries in Python cannot have duplicate keys so if you need the version you have described you will need two parallel lists instead

Comment: Ok i corrected my question.

Comment: @m_callens two parallel lists is also ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> teams = ['A','B','C']
>>> goals = [12,1,9]
>>> d = dict(enumerate([t for t,g in zip(teams, goals) for _ in range(g)], 1))
>>> d[5]
'A'
>>> d[13]
'B'
>>> d[21]
'C'
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
d = {}
count = 1
for team, goal in zip(teams, goals):
    for i in range(goal):
        d[count] = team
        count += 1
```

Comment: i liked your code, `dict(enumerate([t for t,g in zip(teams, goals) for _ in range(g)], 1))`. could you please explain it for me?

Comment: Ok then, given list is [5,13,21]. How to get list: ['A','B','C']??

Comment: `[d[idx] for idx in given_list]`

Answer (score 1):

```
goaldict = {}
goal_num = 1
for position,team in enumerate(teams):
    for goal in range(0, goals[position]):
        goaldict[goal_num] = team
        goal_num = goal_num + 1
```

Comment: `>>> my_dictionary = {1:'A', 2:'B', ...}`